# Simple query gets much slower when I add a LIMIT clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, limit

I have a table (of snmp traps, but that's neither here nor there).

I have a query  which pulls some records, which goes something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM traps_trap 
WHERE summary_id = 1600
ORDER BY traps_trap."trapTime";
```

This responds instantaneously, with 6 records.

When I add `LIMIT 50` (since not all results will have only 6 records), it is very, VERY slow (to the point of not returning at all).

There is an index on the `summary_id` column, I can only assume that it isn't being used for the second query.

I understand that the tool to solve this is `explain`, but I'm not familiar enough with it to understand the results.

The explain analyse verbose for the first (quick) query is as follows:

```
                                                                   QUERY PLAN                                                                       
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Sort  (cost=14491.51..14502.48 rows=4387 width=263) (actual time=0.128..0.130 rows=6 loops=1)
   Output: id, summary_id, "trapTime", packet
   Sort Key: traps_trap."trapTime"
   Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 28kB
   ->  Index Scan using traps_trap_summary_id on public.traps_trap  (cost=0.00..13683.62 rows=4387 width=263) (actual time=0.060..0.108 rows=6 loops=1)
         Output: id, summary_id, "trapTime", packet
         Index Cond: (traps_trap.summary_id = 1600)
 Total runtime: 0.205 ms
(8 rows)
```

explain for the second is:

```
                                               QUERY PLAN                                                
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Limit  (cost=0.00..2538.69 rows=10 width=263)
   ->  Index Scan using "traps_trap_trapTime" on traps_trap  (cost=0.00..1113975.68 rows=4388 width=263)
         Filter: (summary_id = 1600)
(3 rows)
```

I run `VACUUM` and `ANALYZE` daily, I understand that is supposed to improve the plan. Any other pointers?

Comment: Try to create a multicolumn index on columns: summary_id + trapTime (summary_id must be the first column in the index).

Answer (score 1):

Index scan using trapTime is much slower than one using summary_id.
I would try to nest the query (to use plan #1):

```
select * from (
    SELECT * 
    FROM traps_trap 
    WHERE summary_id = 1600
    ORDER BY traps_trap."trapTime"
) t
limit 50;
```

---

Edit:

After doing some tests I learned that simple query nesting (as above) has no effect on the planner. 
To force the planner to use `traps_trap_summary_id` index you can use CTE (my tests confirm this method):

```
with t as (
    SELECT * 
    FROM traps_trap 
    WHERE summary_id = 1600
    ORDER BY traps_trap."trapTime"
)
select * from t
limit 50;
```